# File uploading issue in Yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2

I am developing an application in Yii2 framework.

I am uploading an image using code below and which has worked perfect till now. But now I got an error instant. I don't understand what has happened.

Below is the code of controller where upload file and save take place:

```php
// Upload photo of subcategories...
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
if($model->file) {
    $imageName = rand(1000,100000);
    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/subcategories/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
    $model->sub_category_photo = 'uploads/subcategories/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
}
$model->save();
```

I got below error:

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>       finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\php9A7B.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I also un-comment `extension = fileinfo.dll` in `php.ini` file and restart server.

Comment: Does the directory tmp exist and is accessible? Is the fileinfo.dll extension now enabled or disabled?

Comment: fileinfo.dll is enabled now and its accessible now

Comment: And you haven't changed anything on your code? What else have you done?

Comment: No, It was working but suddenly display error..dont know what happen..Nothing change

Comment: Then it has probably nothing to do with Yii, I guess. Anything else? No harddisk space left? Anyone else that has changed anything on the machine? System updates?

Comment: Lots of space available  in HD. Found same issue..but not getting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998914/yii-framework-2-0-uploading-files-error-finfo-file-failed-to-open-stream-no

Comment: I saw that too. When does the exception occur? On `$model->save()` or `$model->file->saveAs()`? Could you add the stack trace? Btw: this code may produce image names that already exist...

Comment: how about directory permissions?

Comment: Stack trace? You could have a look into the log.

Comment: How stack trace.. help here so i can check log

Comment: Log file should be in runtime/logs/app.log. You may need to enable [debug mode and dev environment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html#defining-constants). I just would like to know if save or saveAs is causing the issue.

Comment: I checked it. I found that 'tmp_name' => ['file' => 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php91B8.tmp'] and I think in tmp folder that does not available...what happen actually

Comment: What? Don't understand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77517/discussion-between-user1780370-and-robsch).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got solutions of this questions.

Call `$model->save();` in controller

before

```
$model->file->saveAs();
```

Means in above code of my questions changed to below

```
// Upload photo of subcategories...
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
if($model->file) {
    $imageName = rand(1000,100000);
    $model->sub_category_photo = 'uploads/subcategories/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
    $model->save();
    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/subcategories/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
} else {
    $model->save();
}
```

Hope this help someone as it helped me and I found answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998914/yii-framework-2-0-uploading-files-error-finfo-file-failed-to-open-stream-no)

Comment: how can it possible when i am uploading multiple files and then save data in database of all uploaded files?

Answer (score 1):

In views > **_form.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In controller:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
```

In actionCreate():

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');            
    if($model->validate() && $model->save()) {                 
        $model->image->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../uploads/'. $model->image);   
        $model->save(); 
    }
}
```

In actionUpdate():

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {           
    $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
    if($model->validate() && $model->save()){
        $model->image->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../uploads/'.$model->image);   
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

In actionDelete($id):

```
unlink($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../../uploads/".$model->image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Model Rule (note skip on empty):
['file', 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'mimeTypes' => 'image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],

//save file
$model->file->saveAs();

//set it to null
$model->file = null;

//now it will save ok
$model->save();
```

I think what happens is once the file is saved, it's cleared out of memory so when the model tries to save it throws an error.